# Calling a constructor with default parameters instead of default constructor

Tags: c#, struct

I want to call a constructor of a struct, that has default values for all parameters. But when I call the parameterless constructor of MyRectangle a not defined constructor get's called. Why is that? Is it possible to not have a not from me created constructor called?

```
using System;

namespace UebungClasses
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyRectangle sixRec = new MyRectangle(3, 2);
            MyRectangle oneRec = new MyRectangle();

            Console.WriteLine("area of six: " + sixRec.Area() + " area of one: " + oneRec.Area());
        }
    }

    public struct MyRectangle
    { 
        public MyRectangle(double w = 1, double l = 1)
        {
            width = w;
            length = l;
            Console.WriteLine("Width: " + width + " Lenght: " + length);
        }

        public double Area()
        {
            return width * length;
        }

        private double width;
        private double length;
    }
}
```

Comment: If `MyRectangle` had been a `class` instead of a `struct`, it would have worked the way you intended. But for historical reasons, any use of `new T()` where `T` is a value type, works the same as `default(T)`.

Comment: Did you try declaring the parameterless constructor private, such as « private MyRectangle() {} »

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, basically. If you use `new MyRectangle()`, it will always prefer the default constructor (meaning: zero init in the case of `struct`).

If you were dealing with integers, one potential workaround would be to use xor with your desired default in the property accessors - this would mean that when the fields are zero, you get the default values from the accessors. Unfortunately, to do this with `double` would require using unsafe code to reinterpret the types.

One other potential solution would be to add a dummy parameter that you can use, for example:

```
new MyRectangle(dummy: true)
```

This `dummy` parameter would do literally nothing *except* allow you to select the custom constructor.

Another final option would be to use a factory method (`static MyRectangle Create(...)`) instead of the constructor.

Comment: Wouldn't you consider a `isNotDefault` flag a viable choice? You'd pay a small penalty on any property access but if its not a problem, its a rather clean way to get custom "default" value behavior in structs.

Comment: @InBetween given the choice, I'd prefer the xor approach - an xor is a simple bit-op that pipelines nicely into a CPU chain and will usually out-perform something that relies on a branch

Comment: I agree, I was referring to the general case where integers are not involved.

Comment: Sad, that i can't do that the way I wanted, but hey, at least I learned something new! Thank You.

Comment: @InBetween I might be entirely too happy to use `unsafe` code - that would barely slow me down :)

Comment: Instead of the XOR thing, you may subtract `1.0`. Something like: `public MyRectangle(double w = 1.0, double l = 1.0) { widthMinusOne = w - 1.0; lengthMinusOne = l - 1.0; }` You would need to add the `1.0` again every time you _read_ the fields (could have a property for that), for example in the `Area` method.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen perhaps, but xor is a cheaper CPU operation than arithmetic - especially floating point arithmetic; plus there's a chance (when talking about floating point) of that messing with the value due to rounding (especially if it triggers a scale change), where-as xor is guaranteed to be side-effect free

Comment: I totally agree. If I were to use my own idea to create a rectangle (smaller than an atomic nucleus in SI units) of width `3.14E-16` and length `2.718E-15`, this subtraction of `1.0` and adding it again would ruin everything. Whereas without this offset thing, the area product `3.14E-16 * 2.718E-15`, will work perfectly with floating points.

Comment: This should definitely go in the official documentation. It’s explained too vaguely in default parameters section. It should be added in the constructors with default parameters section.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the compiler will always resolve first to a valid constructor with no default parameters. Its a bit like with generics, where the non generic overload wins, well here, the non default parameter overload is preferred.

Because structs all have a parameterless constructor, that one will be chosen over yours.

A way around this if you need a different default rectangle could be:

```
public struct MyRectangle
{
    private readonly bool isNotDefault;

    public MyRectangle(double w, double l)
    {
        isNotDefault = true;
        width = w;
        length = l;
    }

    public double Area()
    {
        //Notice the use of the properties,
        //not the backing fields.
        return Width * Length;             
    }

    private readonly double width, length;
    public double Width => isNotDefault ? width: 1;
    public double Length => isNotDefault ? length : 1;

    public override string ToString()
        => $"Width: {Width} Lenght: {Length}";
}
```

Not sure I'd recommend this for a rectangle, after all a zero sized rectangle seems a reasonable choice, but there are cases where the default value really doesn't make sense. A clear example is a struct representing a rational number, where the default value is a mathematical indetermination: `0/0`.

Comment: Yes, sure a default of 0 / 0 is more fitting, but I wondered and "boild down the code" as SE told me to. Thank You for your answer, but I think I will accept the other one.